# Facebook SDK "user_likes" permission causes "Invalid Scope"

Tags: android, facebook, user-permissions, facebook-sdk-4.x

The following is the standard Facebook SDK code I used to request permissions which was working in May 2018.

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes"));
```

However it now returns the following error:

> ERROR: "Invalid Scopes: user_likes. This message is only shown to
>   developers.Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present.
>   Please read documentation for valid permissions at:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions".

I could not find any mention of `user_likes` permission being removed in the developer link above.

Note: `user_likes` permission needs Facebook review. I am testing my app with a Facebook account with the role of admin for the app which means I should be able to use the `user_likes` permission before review.

Comment: Your app needs to be in dev mode, you can not ask users with a role in the app for just any un-reviewed permission any more when it is live.

Comment: thanks, after changing setting to development mode, its working